# Read PNG image from stream with 4 channels

Tags: python, discord.py, opencv

I'm working on a discord bot that accepts all kind of images for OCR purposes. When a user upload a PNG with 4 channels it goes wrong. By that I mean it read the image as almost 100% white, while the actual image is full of colours.

I've tried to convert it with cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR but this doesn't work. However in my pytest it does work. This is probably because I'm using cv2.imread in my pytest which is a bit different from my actual code.

*Code* (broken)

> ```
> for a in supported_attachments:
>   async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
>     async with session.get(a) as res:
>       if res.status == 200:
>         buffer = io.BytesIO(await res.read())
>         arr = np.asarray(bytearray(buffer.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
>         img = cv2.imdecode(arr, -1)
>         if len(img.shape) > 2 and img.shape[2] == 4:
>           print('convert')
>           img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)
>           plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
>           plt.show() 
>         images.append(img)
> ```

*pytest* (works)

> image = cv2.imread('../tests/images/stats/english/kills_png.png',
> cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)

Any suggestions or idea's?

Comment: First step, get rid of the magic number -- `cv2.imdecode(arr, -1)` should be `cv2.imdecode(arr, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)`. Isn't that much easier to understand? And now, if you want `imread` to behave the same way, just call it with the same flag.

Comment: Yes good point, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flag `cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR` is for `cv2.cvtColor()` not for `cv2.imread()`.

All the manifest constants for `cv2.imread()` start with `cv2.IMREADxxx` and are defined [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/d6a/group__imgcodecs__flags.html#ga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80).

Comment: Hmm but by using image = cv2.imread('../tests/images/stats/english/kills_png.png', cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)
in my pytest works perfectly fine, without that flag it doesn't work.

Comment: Not just wrong, with `imread` it's also useless, given that it evaluates to 1, just like the default value of the second argument `IMREAD_COLOR`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, read the link and fixed it.